# Maintaining a cache of huge slack workspace

Tags: caching, slack, slack-api

I need to implement Slack user/channel suggestions dropdown to share something using the user's Slack token. And (AFAIK) Slack doesn't provide any search-by-name features, so the only way is to implement it ourselves.

Currently, I'm thinking of pushing all public channels (most likely, I will have to figure out how to do the same for private ones) and users' data into something like Elastic. And use Slack Events to keep it up-to-date.

Are there any best practices for this task? I'm pretty sure it's a more or less a trivial problem, and I'm not the first one who needs to implement such a solution - but surprisingly enough, I didn't find any off-shelf solutions to this problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Slack's Block Kit feature? It offers both a conversations-select and a users-select dropdown menu that you can embed into messages.
https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/block-elements#select

Comment: Essentially, I need some search API to get suggestions list. AFAIU Slack's Block Kit is intended to use solely in Slack Messages, so it won't work unfortunately